# Update output in dynamic module - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a code that allows to dynamically add modules in a Shiny app. This module is composed of a selectInput and can be added by clicking on the "Add filter" Button.

What I try to do is to put text at the right of each selectInput widget which value update when the user click on the perform Button and is equal to the selection on the selectInput

I don't know how to do. Many tries were unsuccessfull...

The code is the following :

```
library(shiny)

moduleFilterUI <- function(id) {
ns <- NS(id)
uiOutput(ns("SymbolicFilter"))
}


moduleSymbolicFilter <- function(input, output, session) {

output$SymbolicFilter <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 4, selectInput(session$ns("cname"), "Column name", choices =  c(1:5)))
    )
})

}

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
       actionButton("addSymbolicFilterModule", "Add filter"),
        actionButton("Filter", "Perform"),
        uiOutput("symbolicFilters"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    symbolicFilterModules <- list()
    makeReactiveBinding("symbolicFilterModules") 

observeEvent(input$addSymbolicFilterModule, {
    duplicateSymbolicFilterid <- paste0("duplicateSymbolicFilter", input$addSymbolicFilterModule)
    symbolicFilterModules <<- c(symbolicFilterModules, list(moduleSymbolicFilterUI(duplicateSymbolicFilterid)))
    callModule(moduleSymbolicFilter, duplicateSymbolicFilterid)


    shinyjs::disable("addSymbolicFilterModule")
    iLast <- length(symbolicFilterModules)
    for (i in 1:(iLast-1)){
        duplicateSymbolicFilterid <- paste0("duplicateSymbolicFilter", i)
        updateSelectInput(session, paste0(duplicateSymbolicFilterid,"-cname"),
                          selected=input[[paste0(duplicateSymbolicFilterid,"-cname")]])
    }
})


observeEvent(input$Filter,{
    shinyjs::enable("addSymbolicFilterModule")
    iLast <- length(symbolicFilterModules)
    duplicateSymbolicFilterid <- paste0("duplicateSymbolicFilter", iLast)
    cname <- input[[paste0(duplicateSymbolicFilterid,"-cname")]]

    for (i in 1:(iLast)){
        duplicateSymbolicFilterid <- paste0("duplicateSymbolicFilter", i)
        updateSelectInput(session, paste0(duplicateSymbolicFilterid,"-cname"),
                          selected=input[[paste0(duplicateSymbolicFilterid,"-cname")]])

    }
})


output$symbolicFilters <- renderUI({
    symbolicFilterModules
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you had already solved the problem, but... 
you named the module `moduleFilterUI`, but you call `moduleSymbolicFilterUI`...